# how can i use a for loop to count to and count by a number in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, for-loop

Create a program that takes two numbers - one to count to and another to determine what multiple to use to get there.

Here is some sample input:

> Count to: 30  Count by: 5  Output: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30
>
> Count to: 50  Count by: 7  Output: 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49

here is my trial code.

```js
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Count to: "));
var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Count by: "));
for(let i = num2; i <= num1; i+num2){

}
console.log(i);
```

Comment: `i+num2` -> `i += num2`

Comment: Also, the `console.log(i)` needs to be inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below snippet could help you

```js
function count(countTo, countBy) {
  const arr = []
  for (let i = countBy; i <= countTo; i += countBy) {
    arr.push(i)
  }
  console.log(arr.join(', '))
}

count(30, 5)
count(50, 7)
```

Comment: this is great, i have been having a problem with functions but this is very clear

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the value of `i` in your loop as `i+num` does not increase its value:

```js
// Changed the variable names to something more descriptive
// to avoid confusion on larger code bases;
var maxValue = parseInt(prompt("Count to: "));
var stepValue = parseInt(prompt("Count by: "));

// Can also be written as index += stepValue
for(let index = stepValue; index <= maxValue; index = index + stepValue) {
  // Print the current value of index
  console.log(index);  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use modulus operator in your loop with a conditional that checks if the modulus of the number iterated is equal to zero...

Count to: 30 Count by: 5 Output: 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30

```js
let targetNumber = 30;
for(let i = 1; i <= targetNumber; i++){
  if( i % 5 === 0){
  console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Count to: 50 Count by: 7 Output: 7, 14, 21, 28, 35, 42, 49

```js
let targetNumber = 50;
for(let i = 1; i <= targetNumber; i++){
  if( i % 7 === 0){
  console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setup was good, only the `console.log` statement needs to be inside the loop to print.

```
var num1 = parseInt(prompt("Count to: "));
var num2 = parseInt(prompt("Count by: "));
for (let i = num2; i <= num1; i += num2) {
  console.log(i);
}
```